# Replace one of multiple image with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, replace

I have multiple same images. When i click on one of them img need to be replaced. I have JS script:

```
var newsrc = "slide_down";
function changeImage() {
    if ( newsrc == "slide_down" ) {
        document.images["pic"].src = "img/slide_up.png";
        document.images["pic"].alt = "slide_up";
        newsrc  = "slide_up";
    }
    else {
        document.images["pic"].src = "img/arrow.png";
        document.images["pic"].alt = "slide_down";
        newsrc  = "slide_down";
    }
}
```

But when I press the second img, always the first to be replaced. Help please.
Html code of image is `<img src="img/arrow.png" alt="slide_up" class="head" id="pic" onclick="changeImage()">`

Comment: Can you share your html and also where you applied your click handler for clear answers

Comment: all of your `img`s has `id="pic"`?

Comment: @Cherniv Only those that need to be replaced.

Comment: you mean more than one?

Comment: @Cherniv Yes. It's img for slide up and slide down post. I have many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var newsrc = "slide_down";
function changeImage() {
    if ( newsrc == "slide_down" ) {
       this.src = "img/slide_up.png";
        this.alt = "slide_up";
        newsrc  = "slide_up";
    }
    else {
        this.src = "img/arrow.png";
        this.alt = "slide_down";
        newsrc  = "slide_down";
    }
}
```